# how to prevent a user from maliciously alter a query (laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, encryption

i have a form which sends the following data to the server:

```
<!-- This form pulls, using JS event handlers, data from the table record selected -->
<form id="edit_form" action="" method="POST" role="form">
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>ID do Cartão</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idcartao_edit" placeholder="ID do Cartão" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome do aluno</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"
          name="nome_aluno_edit" placeholder="Nome do Aluno" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email_edit" placeholder="E-mail" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Curso</label>
      <select id="curso_edit" class="form-control" name="curso_edit">
          <option>Seleccionar curso...</option>
          @foreach($curso_list as $curso)
            <option value="{{$curso->encrypted_id}}">{{$curso->curso}}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Triénio</label>
    <!-- Trigerred by a JS event handler when a curso_edit option is selected -->
        <select id="trienio_edit" class="form-control" name="trienio_edit">
            <option>Seleccionar triénio...</option>
        </select>
  </div>
<!-- Triggered when user opens a bootstrap modal. Pulls the value from the table record selected -->
<input type="hidden" id="idcartao_original" name="idcartao_original" value="" />
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editar aluno</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

on the server side, the data inputed by the user is processed like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Aluno $aluno)
{   
    $id_aluno = $aluno->where('id_cartao', '=', $request->input('idcartao_original'))->first()->id;

    $aluno = $aluno->find($id_aluno);

    $aluno->id_cartao = $request->input('idcartao_edit');
    $aluno->nome = $request->input('nome_aluno_edit');
    $aluno->email = $request->input('email_edit');
    $aluno->trienio_id = decrypt($request->input('trienio_edit'));

    $aluno->save();

    return redirect()->route('alunos');
}
```

the problem with this form is that the user can change the id to a different one, and the query will load an entirely non-intended different user. like changing the value from 1 to 2, for example, on this input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idcartao_original" name="idcartao_original" value="" />
```

so instead of loading a model like this:

```
ID: 1
ID Cartão: 1011000
Nome: Joseph Wilson
E-mail: joseph.67@gmail.com
```

it will load a model like this:

```
ID: 2
ID Cartão: 1011001
Nome: John Black
E-mail: johnblackwilliams@gmail.com
```

and proceed to change the data of a, like i said, an entirely non-intentional different model.

i've already tried to send encrypted ids using an ajax call to the server but considering the inputs can end up like this:

**curso_edit option** (**the encrypted values are the encrypted ids of the "TAI" option, for example**)

```
<option value="eyJpdiI6ImJqZGJKOGVBOFMyQ0huUXdKVHhFMXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidWpROWRrSUFYREszbTF2Q24zTkVoZz09IiwibWFjIjoiM2QxYWViNzU0NWIyN2M2ZGQzMmMwYWJjYWUxZTAyYzBkOGNlNWQ0MDAzMjIyNzA1YWExNzg5ODA2MmNhYjBiMCJ9">TAI</option>

<option value="eyJpdiI6IjRVMWowT0cwYWxVeWpOXC9YaW0yRlJnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkF1VmZoTGdPT3BsTnR3MWV0bXhGdkE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImY2ZDRiOGIyZDFmMjdmNjhkYzA4ZDMzNGVmNzY2NWZkYzhiMzA1ODljMmM1Njk3ODA1ZGFkZjQ4MWI5ZGM4MzcifQ==">TAL</option>
```

and so on...

**trienio_edit option**

```
<option value="eyJpdiI6ImpmTjBHSk8zTzQ0NmFLR0t1SkxhVXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiOTFYOEluYXFWQk4xMVYxYk1JUHZ0Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiMWZhZDU0NmE2MWQwODliYzg3ZDEzM2Q5NTM3NWJiYTUxMzM5ZTQyMjMwMDBjZDI2OGE4ODEyZjAzNjk3MTVlYyJ9">2015-2018</option>

<option value="eyJpdiI6IjhvUTNGbnNZbG1Ja0d0NktFZFRNaGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicGdKeWtZa1VEeHpDTzQ5QVFhRHcrdz09IiwibWFjIjoiM2EwM2IzZDY3Y2VmZWI4N2QzNTUyZGVlMTUxNjVkZjFiOWUzNGViYjdiNTFiMGZmMDEwMjBhY2JlYTg3ZDg3MiJ9">2014-2017</option>
```

and so on...

even if the user doesn't have access to the ids in their raw state, he can still inspect the element using chrome or other browser and pull the encrypted id corresponding to the curso/trienio they want to maliciously change (those present in the options)

so even if i send an ajax call to the server in order to pull an encrypted id corresponding to the item being altered in the form like this:

```
query by corresponding encrypted curso_edit id/value, encrypted trienio_edit id/value, unique email
```

the user can inspect the javascript code, replace the encrypted curso_edit, trienio_edit value, and e-mail by another one present in the options above.

how can i fix this ?

p.s - dont be too harsh on me. this problem is somewhat difficult to explain and i've tried my best to explain it, if you need more details say

**by the way:** i've organized the model by id, id cartao, nome, email and by using relationships, trienio and curso. this is somewhat a school management system, and by virtue of that, anybody that knows this info: course (curso), year (trienio), card id (id cartao, those are school cards with an id on it) ,name (nome) and email of a student will easily guess the columns values. i need something stronger and unguessable. and considering a school environment, those informations are very easily obtainable

Comment: You should implement logic in the FormRequest class's `authorize` method - if the user doesn't have access to that ID, it should reject them. See the example at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#authorizing-form-requests

Comment: this is an admin panel for a somewhat intuitive database management. i'm planning to implement roles soon though.

Comment: you can also use a combination of `id` and another column to find the model you want to edit. it's true that user may know the `id` to change it but she may hardly know the other column's value. you can do it for example with a combination of `id` and `token`

Comment: i've organized the model by the id, id cartao, nome, email and by using relationships, trienio and curso. this is somewhat a school management system, and by virtue of that, anybody that knows this info: course (curso), year (trienio), card id (id cartao, those are school cards with an id on it) ,name (nome) and email of a student will easily guess the columns values. i need something stronger and unguessable.

Comment: Well... how do you determine on the front end what data they can see/edit?  Repeat a similar process on the backend when saving it...

Comment: @BadLaravelProgrammer You can use encrypted value instead of real ID.